# Compile and create instance of a new java program from existing java program

Tags: java

I am writing a java program in eclipse to extract forms from lotusnotes db. Whenever I get a form I need to create a .java file containng a class with same name as of form. Then I have to compile this new .java class which gives me .class file & hence I can create an instance of that new class.  I need to know whether this approach of creating,compiling & instantiating a new class is possible from a single existing java program.

My pseudocode goes below

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import de.bea.domingo.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
public class LotusNotesDBExtraction
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws DNotesException,IOException
{
    DNotesFactory factory = DNotesFactory.getInstance();
    DSession session = factory.getSession();
    DDatabase database = session.getDatabase("", "employee.nsf");
    List formlist=database.getForms();
    //System.out.println("Number of forms are :"+formlist.size());
    for(int i=0;i<formlist.size();i++)
    {
        DForm formn=(DForm)(formlist.get(i));
        DForm formname= database.getForm(formn.getName());

        **//Creating a class in a file
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter("D:\\Lotusnotesformfiles\\"+formn.getName()+".java",true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outputfile);
        out.write("public class "+formn.getName()+" {");
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();**

        try
        {
             **//Compile the class here**   
                            Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd javac \"D:\\Lotusnotesformfiles\\"+formn.getName()+".java\"");   
            System.out.println("compiled");
         }   
          catch(IOException x)
        {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
                **//instantiate the new class here**
}
}
```

But I am not able to get .class file for the new class. Can I instantiate the new class in the same program?? I was stuck at this point. Can any please help me

Comment: This is not an answer, but I am interested in why you want to have a class for each form available in the same program? How do you want to use that class?

Comment: I need to create an object for each document of the form and pass it to the another guy who is gonna dump the data in salesforce db

Comment: Do you want to create an _instance_ (object) or a _class_?

Comment: Btw, you asked the same question aleady here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582159/dynamically-create-java-class-for-a-lotus-notes-form

Comment: after you instantiate the class (and run within the current JVM), do you want to keep the java source file exists on the system?

Comment: @michael667, I want to create the class, compile it & then create an instance of it, all in the same program

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do much, if not all, of this using the [Reflection API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), which allows you to modify classes at runtime, inspect their contents, and even dynamically load classes (for example, after compilation).

Comment: Cant I achieve this without using reflection API?

Comment: The Relection API is built precisely to conquer these sorts of problems. So, no, you can't really do this without the Reflection API. This has to do with how the JVM starts up, and at what point `.class` files are loaded and made available. The Reflection API allows you to load `.class` files while the app is running, as opposed to only at the beginning of the JVM's life.